# mongodb $slice aggregate operator issue when third argument is 0 { $slice: [ <array>, <position>, <n> ] }

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Consider the below Mongodb Query.

```
  db.groups.aggregate([{
        $match: {
        _id: {
            $in: [220]
        },
        active: true
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
        myArr: {
            $slice: ["$arr", -1, 0]
        },
        name: 1
        
        }
    }]).pretty()
```

When I execute this query I encounter error:

```
2020-12-05T19:16:43.002-0500 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: Error: command failed: {
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1607213793, 1),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Third argument to $slice must be positive: 0",
    "code" : 28729,
    "codeName" : "Location28729",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1607213793, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
} : aggregate failed :
```

As per the $slice documentation, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/
the third argument ('n') to the $slice aggregate operator cannot be negative if the second argument 'position' is specified. I calculate the third argument value to 0 which means, I expect 0 array elements as the result. However, I encounter errmsg" : "Third argument to $slice must be positive: 0".

Please suggest if my understanding is incorrect as the query doesn't execute as I expect.

Comment: Why use `$slice` if you want an empty array?

Comment: 0 is not a hardcoded value, I calculate to 0 , for simplicity I hardcoded to 0. I use some logic to calculate number elements to pull from array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need to use calculated value, you can use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)

```
{
  $project:{
    "arrayName":{
        $cond:[{$eq:["$calculatedField",0]}, [], $sliceOperationGoesHere]
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I filed a issue with mongo https://jira.mongodb.org/projects/MONGOSH/issues/MONGOSH-489?filter=allopenissues

Answer (score 0):

`0` is not a valid value for slice when `position` is specified because it's not a positive number. When you calculate the number of elements to return in `$slice`, if it's `0` you can instead project an empty array like so:

```
{
  $project: {
    myArr: [],
    name: 1
  }
}
```

And if it's greater than 0 you can pass the `$slice` operator to the `$project` stage as you are currently doing.